# Yarn install errors with "ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, yarnpkg, github-actions

I have a `Dockerfile` and when I run it locally, everything works fine, however my build through GitHub actions seems to fail, the error I am getting is:

> ```
> error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/runner/work/akira/akira/README.md'".
> ```

I tried to remove the `yarn.lock` but without success, a full log of the build that fails can be found [here](https://github.com/pandaniell/akira/runs/912084560), my `Dockerfile` is below:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:14.0.0 AS base
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

FROM base as builder
COPY ./lerna.json .
COPY ./package.json .
COPY ./tsconfig.json .
COPY ./yarn.lock .
COPY ./packages/akira/prisma ./packages/akira/prisma
COPY ./packages/akira/src ./packages/akira/src
COPY ./packages/akira/types ./packages/akira/types
COPY ./packages/akira/package*.json ./packages/akira/
COPY ./packages/akira/tsconfig.json ./packages/akira
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
RUN yarn build

FROM builder as migrate
RUN yarn workspace akira prisma migrate up --experimental

FROM base AS app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/yarn.lock .
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/packages/akira/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/packages/akira/prisma ./prisma
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/packages/akira/package.json .
RUN yarn install --production
USER node
ENV NODE_ENV=production
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```

Comment: Which command are you using to run this locally? It looks like GitHub actions is not actually using the Dockerfile...

Comment: docker build . 
GitHub is using the Dockerfile because that’s where the yarn install —production command comes from, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your [GitHub Actions workflow](https://github.com/pandaniell/akira/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml),
or the log from the failing build that you linked, it seems to be running `yarn` commands outside of docker.

It looks like `yarn` is struggling with the README symlink, not sure why, but as it seems you want to build with docker, I would try the following:

Replace this part of the yaml

```yaml
- name: Use Node.js
  uses: actions/setup-node@master
  with:
    node-version: 14.4.0

- name: Install dependencies
  run: yarn --frozen-lockfile

- name: Build packages
  run: yarn build
```

with something like

```yaml
- name: Build docker image
  run: docker build .
```

**Edit**:

As pointed out in below comment, the Dockerfile includes a side-effect of deploying database migrations.

If you don't want to run everything from the Dockerfile in the Build pipeline,
you can leverage [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and stop at a specific stage.

I.e., move the migrations into its own stage:

```
FROM node:14.0.0 AS base
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

FROM base as builder
COPY ./lerna.json .
<< lines omitted >>
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
RUN yarn build

FROM builder AS migr
RUN yarn workspace akira prisma migrate up --experimental

FROM base AS app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/yarn.lock .
<< lines omitted >>
```

Then you can stop after the `builder` stage with

```
docker build --target builder .
```

**Edit 2**:

Or you could keep the build pipeline and Dockerfile as it is, and instead fix the broken symlink, i.e. revert commit `0c87fa3`

Comment: I don’t think that would be a good solution since the dockerfile was made to run on Heroku, it fails because it cannot run migrations in GitHub actions https://github.com/pandaniell/akira/runs/912437469?check_suite_focus=true - about the symlink: I created it on Linux and everything worked fine back then, recently I pushed through windows and I did see a Readme change but it didn’t actually change anything visible as far as I know https://github.com/pandaniell/akira/commit/0c87fa3c5368c580ae7ccb4a41f3539d03addd18#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8 Here is the diff

Comment: Okay, well at this point you have two options. 1-Update your Dockerfile so that the `build` workflow can use it without applying migrations or 2-Investigate why `yarn --frozen-lockfile` fails outside of docker. I don't know how to do 2, but I'll edit by answer with how you could do 1 

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer with how you could update the Dockerfile to only run the "builder" stage. Otherwise you could probably fix the README symlink by removing and recreating it in linux. If I clone the repo to linux it also shows broken symlink for the README.

Comment: Sorry for comment spam... If I do `git revert 0c87fa3c5368` (the commit you linked for the README change), then the symlink works again for me, so you could probably just do that

Comment: Thank you! I reverted the README and changed the build step